# React overriding child element styles

Tags: reactjs

I have the following structure

```
<button>
  <OtherComponent />
</button>
```

OtherComponent just gives a < span /> with an icon, with its own styles.
I want to pass a style to **button** to override OtherComponent's styles, eg. set the margin to 0. I've tried (doesn't work)

```
<button style={{ 'span': { margin: 0 }}}>
  <OtherComponent />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Inline style only affects the current element that you are applying to**

If you want to style a child element then you should select it from a CSS file.

**So in your parent component you would do:**

```
import React from "react";
import { OtherComponent } from "./components/OtherComponent";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**And then in styles.css file:**

```
.App span {
  margin: 0;
}
```

---

[Complete Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sound-y4r48)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add div/Button in backend and override style like style={{ marginLeft: "100px" }} with double curle braces.

**Parent Component**

```
import "./styles.css";
import OtherComponent from "./OtherComponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button style={{ marginLeft: "100px" }}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./buttonStyle.css";

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button className="button">Style Button</button>;
  }
}

export default OtherComponent;
```

**[CodeSandBox Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/spanothercomponent-dfmjj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**